# Passing parameters to YQL using Java

Tags: java, search, yql

I am using the following code:

```
String zip = "75227";
String str = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20Title%2C%20Address%2C%20" +
            "City%2C%20State%2C%20Phone%2C%20Distance%20from%20local.search%20where%20query%3D%22" +
            "food%20pantries%22%20and%20zip%3D%22" + zip +"%22%20and%20(category%3D%2296927050%22%20or" +
            "%20category%3D%2296934498%22)%20%7C%20sort(field%3D%22Distance%22)";

Document doc = Jsoup.connect(str).get();
```

and it is producing the results I want by replacing the zip code value. I would like to also change the location. I tried doing the same I did with the zip code by doing this:

```
String zip = "32207";

String service = "food pantry";

String testOne = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20Title%2C%20Address%2C%20" +
            "City%2C%20State%2C%20Phone%2C%20Distance%20from%20local.search%20where%20query%3D%22" +
            service + "%22%20and%20zip%3D%22" + zip +"%22%20and%20(category%3D%2296927050%22%20or" +
            "%20category%3D%2296934498%22)%20%7C%20sort(field%3D%22Distance%22)";
```

When used this way the variable "service" gave me an error.

I initially tried to use the yql table like this:

```
String search = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=";
String table = "select Title, Address, City, State, Phone, Distance from local.search where " +
            "query=\"food pantries\" and zip=\"75227\" and (category=\"96927050\" or category=" +
            "\"96934498\") | sort(field=\"Distance\")";

String searchText = search + table;
```

UPDATE:

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=505, URL=http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20Title%2C%20Address%2C%20City%2C%20State%2C%20Phone%2C%20Distance%20from%20local.search%20where%20query%3D%22food pantry%22%20and%20zip%3D%2232207%22%20and%20(category%3D%2296927050%22%20or%20category%3D%2296934498%22)%20%7C%20sort(field%3D%22Distance%22)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:418)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:393)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:159)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:148)
at org.jsoup.examples.HtmlToPlainText.main(HtmlToPlainText.java:86)
```

However, this did not work either. Any ideas on how I can do this search and provide the service and zip code as variables?

Comment: Harshit, I have updated the post showing the error I am getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried replacing `String service = "food pantry";` with `String service = "food%20pantry";` ?

EDIT:

and it is "food pantry" or "food pantries"... ?

Comment: It worked when I added the "%20" to the string. The form doesn't matter, I get the same results if it is plural or singular.

Comment: Perfect, don't forget to accept the answer if it helped to solve the problem